# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'or'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why do I get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'or'`?

```
create or replace view view_jab
as select * from jabatan
where kojab = 3
with check option constraint viewJab_ck
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'or'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near 'with'.

Comment: Please review the answer given below.

Answer (score 3):

You can drop the view if it already exists, and then create it afterwards.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('view_jab') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP VIEW view_jab
END

CREATE VIEW view_jab
AS
SELECT * FROM jabatan
WHERE kojab = 3
WITH CHECK OPTION
```

Note that I removed the `CONSTRAINT` from your view, because AFAIK a view cannot have any integrity constraints on it.  Please read [here](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/45721/how-do-i-create-a-constraint-on-a-view.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534919/how-to-make-create-or-replace-view-work-in-sql-server) for more information.

Comment: You can just drop the view in first code and cfeate it in second block in order to not duplicate code...