# SQL Server how to create a view in a specific database on a remote server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am writing a dynamic SQL statement to create view on a remote server in a specific database. The SQL statement I generate gets executed on the master database. If I use use the 3 part naming convention in the `CREATE VIEW` statement does not help.

```
--QUERY
SELECT 
    'IF OBJECT_ID(N'''+ ss.name +'.view_' + so.name + ''') IS NULL
        EXECUTE (''CREATE VIEW ' + ss.name + '.view_' + so.name + ' AS SELECT * FROM REMOTEDATABASE.' + ss.name + '.' + so.name + ''') AT [REMOTESERVER]' 
   FROM sys.objects so
   JOIN sys.schemas ss
     ON so.[schema_id] = ss.[schema_id] 
  WHERE so.[type] = 'U';

--Query Result
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.view_Test') IS NULL 
    EXECUTE ('CREATE VIEW dbo.view_Test AS SELECT * FROM REMOTEDATABASE.dbo.Test') AT [REMOTESERVER]
```

Comment: Whatever the answer is it will be out of date as of SQL 2016 SP1 -- new command -- `CREATE OR ALTER VIEW <viewname>`.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/11/17/create-or-alter-another-great-language-enhancement-in-sql-server-2016-sp1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server equivalent to Oracle's CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163246/sql-server-equivalent-to-oracles-create-or-replace-view)

Comment: Using * in a view is not a good idea. If the table structure changes your view will NOT update itself to include the new columns. Even more confusing if a new column is added and another dropped the values in your view can shift columns.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Sean Lange: I am not using SELECT *, I was using that just for deomostration. Xedni: If I include USE <database> CREATE VIEW I get create view should be the only statement in the batch error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a view in a specific database at a remote server, try something like this:

```
EXECUTE ('USE YourDatabase EXEC(''CREATE VIEW YourView AS SELECT 1 AS SomeColumn'')') AT YourRemoteServer
```

Comment: This is a useful, hard answer to a useful, rare question. This deserves 1000 likes, not the difference between inner and left join.

Answer (score -1):

The below worked for me:

```
USE YourDatabaseName  

GO  

CREATE VIEW [ViewName]  
AS  
SELECT 1
```