# creating functions by conditons

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to create functions if they doesn't exists and update when they exists.

But mssql says that is wrong syntax near function.

```
 IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects where name='CreateJson' AND type='U' )
Begin
Create function [dbo].CreateJson
(
    @String  nvarchar(4000),
    @Param0  SQL_VARIANT = NULL
)
returns nvarchar(4000)
as
begin
    declare @Null nvarchar(4) = N'NULL';
    return  replace(@String, N'{0}', cast(isnull(@Param0, @Null) as nvarchar(4000)));
end

end
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects where name='CreateJson' AND type='U' )
Begin

Alter function [dbo].CreateJson
(
    @String  nvarchar(4000),
    @Param0  SQL_VARIANT = NULL

)
returns nvarchar(4000)
as
begin
    declare @Null nvarchar(4) = N'NULL';
     return  replace(@String, N'{0}', cast(isnull(@Param0, @Null) as nvarchar(4000)));
       end
End
Go
```

How I can make update/create functions by condition?

Comment: Instead, drop the function if it exists and then always re-create it.

Comment: This is finally available in 2016!!! Create or Alter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to conditionally drop it:
(like [Sql Server equivalent to Oracle's CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163246/sql-server-equivalent-to-oracles-create-or-replace-view))

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[CreateJson]') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[CreateJson]
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CreateJson]
AS
--
```

Comment: For procedures I should use the same behavior?

Comment: You could do that. I usually do. You could use this approach for everything but tables, (if you don't want to keep your data)

Comment: Do you know how I can do it for types cause procedures have references to type it don't see types